# I don't see the animation of the sprite

Tags: c++, sfml

This is code after includes:

```
Sprite player;
Texture playerTexture;
IntRect playerContainer(0, 0, 32, 32);
Vector2f playerPosition;

int playerDirection = 0; // 0 - fwd, 1 - back, 2 - stay
```

This is animation update method:

```
void updateAnims(Clock clock, float time) {
  if(time > 0.3f) {
    if(playerDirection == 0) playerContainer.top = 0;
    else if(playerDirection == 1) playerContainer.top = 32;
    else if(playerDirection == 2) playerContainer.top = 64;

    if(playerContainer.left == 96) playerContainer.left = 0;
    else playerContainer.left += 32;

    player.setTextureRect(playerContainer);
    clock.restart();
  }
}
```

and this method is updated in "int main()" method.

```
int main() {
  // Init window
  RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800, 600), "RPG");
  Clock gameClock;
  Clock animClock;
  float gameTime;
  float animTime;

  // Setting up the player
  playerTexture.loadFromFile("player.png");
  player.setTexture(playerTexture);
  player.setTextureRect(playerContainer);
  player.setScale(Vector2f(3.f, 3.f));
  playerPosition.x = 30;
  playerPosition.y = 120;
  player.setPosition(playerPosition);

  while(window.isOpen()) {
    Event event;
    while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
      if(event.type == Event::Closed) {
        window.close();
      }
    }

    checkInputs(gameTime);

    animTime = animClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
    updateAnims(animClock, animTime);

    window.clear();

    gameTime = gameClock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds();
    gameClock.restart();

    window.display();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Turns out that sprite is created in main method, gets texture and texture shape, gets position, but not drawn. Why?

I think think the problem is in animation method but I tried different variations of solutions.

Comment: `void updateAnims(Clock clock, float time)` -- The first parameter is suspicious, as you're passing `clock` by value.  That `clock` parameter is *not* the same `animClock` you have in `main` -- it is only a copy, which gets destroyed as soon as that function returns.  Is that intentional?  If not, then change that function to `void updateAnims(Clock& clock, float time)` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Alas, it had no effect

Comment: It may not have had an effect, but it *definitely* changed your `main` program into having `animClock` actually be updated.  Maybe you should revisit your debugging session(s) with that change in mind.  Up until now, you were always dealing with an `animClock` that was never updated -- now you are.

Comment: How can I debug this program?

Comment: By using...a debugger?  Your compiler comes with a debugger (every major compiler comes with one).

Comment: Maybe I can do this with gdb?

Comment: What IDE are you using (if you're using one)?  Codeblocks for example?  Usually gdb integration is within the IDE.  If you're using pure `g++` using the command-line, then gdb is the debugger and you just need to learn the low level commands for it.  Also, for graphical apps, when I debugged them (a long time ago), it was always advantageous to have a dual monitor setup, where the debugged code is running in one window, and the graphical output in the other window.  Otherwise it gets tedious debugging these types of apps with a single monitor.

Comment: No... I'm using Atom with gcc compiler \_(•~•)_/

Comment: On linux i tried code::blocks but controls on this ide is not comfortable for me

Comment: You can also try Eclipse or Visual studio code, which have more opportunities for customization. Also, both of them can debug C++ code nearly to "out of the box". And there are lots of guide's on the internet how to debug applications with them. CodeBlocks is good enough too. At least it is a complete IDE, not a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `window.draw(player)` method between `window.clear()` and `window.display()` to actually draw player sprite on screen.